# I am Migrating data. How do i remove the errors on my column names?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

Migrating SQL tables from MSSQL to Postgresql using Pentaho Data Integration Having errors when running the job. I think that i have to put double quotes on the column but idont know where to add it.[image]

Comment: You shouldn't _create_ columns or tables with double quotes. Then you don't have those problems to begin with. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i had a bunch of this problems before in this Db and adding double quotes to column names that are also reserved keywords (eg Status, Password, etc) actually fixed the problem but its not working with role